# Stopping IIS 7.5 from passing non-existent pages to Coldfusion

Tags: iis-7, coldfusion

Coldfusion is currently handling *.cfm and *.html pages. If I request a non-existing page, such as www.example.com/sadfasdfasd.cfm, IIS still passes the request off to the Coldfusion handler instead of directing to the IIS 404 error page. The Coldfusion handler responds with the Debugger page stating that the file is not found. How can I get IIS to check if a file exists before passing it to the handler. If it doesn't exist, I'd like it to display the 404 error page. Currently my error pages are setup to provide detailed errors for both local and remote.

Comment: Probably a better question for server fault but try searching google for "Custom 404 IIS ColdFusion" to get started.

Comment: We could not figure out a way to get IIS to manage the error page, so we ended up letting Coldfusion take care of it. We setup the Missing Template Handler (Coldfusion Admin > Server Settings > Settings > Error Handlers) to map to our error page. This is working for us.

Answer (score 1):

If you go into IIS and turn off detailed error messages, it will display the IIS error rather than letting coldfusion handle it.

If you have access to the IIS Manager, go to the site > Error pages > "edit feature" on the right side.  There is probably equivalent code you can put into your web.config file to handle this too.

You can choose any of the other options depending on your needs.

Please note this is also the feature that allows you to see the coldfusion errors from coldfusion's debugger.

Comment: Okay, I tried this. I switched to Custom errors and setup a custom 404 page. Still, when I request an invalid .cfm or .html page I see the Coldfusion error instead of IIS. If I request other file types (.gif, .asp, .php) I get the custom 404.

Comment: hmmm on my dev box, its working as I decribed above.  Not sure.  Did you try restarting IIS?

Comment: Yes, I restarted and I'm still getting the Coldfusion error page. It seems the handler is taking precedence.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an **httpErrors** entry to your root web.config file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" path="404.html" responseMode="File" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Your custom 404.html page should also reside in the root folder.